# Preventing script with if/else and user agent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Fancybox 2, and I'm a javascript (and the jquery library) newb.

I want to prevent the popup from firing when the user agent is 'ipad.'

I just cannot see why the following does not work:
The popup is prevented from firing a second time by a cookie that's also dropped when the popup fires, and that works fine.

```
var check_cookie = $.cookie('popupcookie');

    $(window).load(function() {

        if (check_cookie) {
            true
        } else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {

        } else {
            $.fancybox('#yt', {
                'afterShow': function() {
                    $.cookie('popupcookie', 'value', {
                        expires: 7
                    });
                }

            });
        }

    });
```

Thanks for any help I receive with this.

Comment: Couldn't you just return false?

Comment: What do you mean by *when the user agent is 'ipad.'*?? the term *user agent* is usually used to indicate the browser AFAIK

Comment: As I understand it, any mobile device or browser has a user-agent, which is more (or less) specific to that device.